# How can I make the borders of my map thicker Google Geomap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, geography

I'm using a dhtml map that I'm [deploying to google appengine](http://www.koolbusiness.com/_/index_india.html). Now I'd like to make the borders darker and thicker. How can it be done? I have this map deployed

[image]

And my mockup looks like the following

[image] Can we try and make my map look more like the mockup? The code I have so far is this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        path { fill: #ffc801; }
        :hover { fill: #fcafff; }
      </style>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

        function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

       data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); 
       data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});var ivalue = new Array();

       var options = {
       backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:25 },
       colorAxis:  {minValue: 0, maxValue: 0,  colors: []},
       legend: 'none',    
       backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:25 },   
       datalessRegionColor: '#ffc801',
       displayMode: 'regions', 
       enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
       resolution: 'provinces',
       sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
       region:'IN',
       keepAspectRatio: true,
       width:600,
       height:400,
       tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'focus', isHtml: false}   
       };
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization')); 
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        if (selection.length == 1) {
        var selectedRow = selection[0].row;
        var selectedRegion = data.getValue(selectedRow, 0);
        if(ivalue[selectedRegion] != '') { document.location = ivalue[selectedRegion];  }
        }
        });
       chart.draw(data, options);
     }
     </script>

     <div id='visualization'></div>>
  </body>

</html>
```

### Update

I changed to code according to the answer. Now I don't get the result I expected. Here is the now code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        path { fill: #ffc801; }
        :hover { fill: #fcafff; }
      </style>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

        function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

       data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); 
       data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});var ivalue = new Array();

       var options = {
       backgroundColor: { fill: '#FFF', stroke: '#000', strokeWidth: 75 },
       colorAxis:  {minValue: 0, maxValue: 0,  colors: []},
       legend: 'none',
       datalessRegionColor: '#ffc801',
       displayMode: 'regions', 
       enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
       resolution: 'provinces',
       sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
       region:'IN',
       keepAspectRatio: true,
       width:600,
       height:400,
       tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'focus', isHtml: false}   
       };
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization')); 
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        if (selection.length == 1) {
        var selectedRow = selection[0].row;
        var selectedRegion = data.getValue(selectedRow, 0);
        if(ivalue[selectedRegion] != '') { document.location = ivalue[selectedRegion];  }
        }
        });
       chart.draw(data, options);
     }
     </script>

     <div id='visualization'></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

When I run the above code then I get a dark area around the map instead of thicker borders. What can be done?

### Update

If I use an `iframe` then the zoom does not crop the map area and the hovering is not working as expected.

```
path {
  stroke: #555;
}
#wrapper2 { width: 450px; height: 450px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }

#scaled-frame { width: 400px; height: 400px; border: 0px; }

#scaled-frame {

zoom: 0.61;
overflow: hidden;
-moz-transform: scale(0.61);

-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;

-o-transform: scale(0.61);

-o-transform-origin: 0 0;

-webkit-transform: scale(0.61);

-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;

}



@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

#scaled-frame  { zoom: 1;  }

}



<div id="wrapper2">
    <iframe id="scaled-frame" src="/_/mapframe.html" height="300" width="500" ></iframe>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Does your DOM create SVG tag?

Comment: @BrianS I don't know. I can look if it does if I know where to look. I also read the manual several times and the manual didn't say nything about what I'm trying to achieve (display only India and with thicker borders). I think it should be feasible but I cn not yet seem to accomplish it.

Comment: I can help you if i see the actual page? i used d3.js before, this sound similar

Comment: Alright, you may have a look at the page with code http://plnkr.co/edit/DvUzclRXB4l1OcuZ6yxJ?p=preview The 2 features I want to add are a) Thicker borders and b) Display India only and not also the neighbours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `stroke` CSS property on element `<path>` to get a thicker border,
this is a [SVG HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp) feature.

**In your `.css` file add this:**

```
path {
  stroke: #555;
}
```

To display india only, you need to set the `scale` property to what best fit your HTML5 canavas. Checkout the framework API you use and figure out how to manage scale.

Comment: Thanks. It is definitely improved now. I could not however find any info about the `scale` property when googling it. If you can you are most welcome to supply more information about it.

Comment: did you search scale property for javascript framework or css?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find something I can use from that search. The frameword D3 appeared in the search. I don't think I can use info about that though. I googled for scale property google geochart with no success. We have a [Plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DvUzclRXB4l1OcuZ6yxJ?p=preview) of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I see, there is no scale property in that document. We have to figure out a hack. Try to but the map in `<iframe>` with `overflow: hidden;` and css `zoom: 2 ;` property.

Comment: Ok. I tried to do it with an `iframe` but the zoom didn't crop the map. I updated the question with my result. I'm somewhat out of ideas what to do now so please if you know how to fix my map can you tell me some idea.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz i don't think you can do anything else. your other option is to use other frameworks (like d3.js) or create a javascript function specially for the map (take a lot of time)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think time is on my side and that the functionality will come with new versions of the framework, or that I can achieve it myself in a manner similar to what we said here...

Comment: how do you apply this to the path as it's nested within some werid <g> elements?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried change the value in

```
<style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    path { fill: #ffc801; }
    :hover { fill: #fcafff; }
  </style>
```

Try to add rule for stroke in both path and :hover like this

```
path { fill: #ffac; stroke:#fff; }
:hover { fill: #fcafff; stroke:#000;}
```

This solution will make the selected region be able to show a black stroke and a white stroke when its not hovered. Well, however, for some regions on the map it doesn't work appropriately, you have to hover one the edge to get the black stroke. But I believe this gives us a hint to the right solution right?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#coloring), you should be able to set

```
backgroundColor: { fill: '#FFF', stroke: '#000', strokeWidth: 30 }
```

This will set the areas of the map to have a white fill with a black border with a border-width of 30px. You should play around with the strokeWidth value to get it to the size you want. Also, it looks like you have this defined twice. Remove one of the backgroundColor definitions.